# Http call as service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am brand new to Angular and I am attempting to make a simple http request for data. How do I access this data in my component? I am getting the error 'Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'

@Injectable()
export class FetchData {

    private url: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    get(){
        return this.http.get(this.url).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }

}
```

table.component.ts

```
import { FetchData } from './datatable.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.css']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  Data: FetchData

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Data.get()
  }

}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 1):

You need to "Inject" the service in your component and also make the subscription in your component.

In your service you should "map" your response.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class FetchData {

        private url: string = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
        constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

        get(){
            return this.http.get(this.url).map(data => {
              return data.json();
            })
        }

    }
```

Your component:

```
import { FetchData } from './datatable.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datatable',
  templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.css']
})
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fetchDataService: FetchData) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchDataService.get().subscribe(res => {
       console.log(response);
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I think the map part is not necessary anymore with the new HttpClient that he is using. This practice was done in earlier versions with Http module, but HttpClient made it obsolete if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Looks like you're right, I checked the documentation and I don't see the map operator anymore.

Comment: I just checked the version announcment and in the official blog post for the version 5 it is also stated like that [https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private dataService: FetchData) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.get()
}}
```